# Is there an after-cast delay in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there an after-cast delay in League of Legends? Specifically I think I've noticed it on Wukong. When I am using nimbus strike to harass, I want to use decoy immediately afterwards to try and stealth and run out of range again so I can harass without the opponent poking back at me. However it seems there is about a .5 second delay before I can decoy and in this time the enemy can usually get one hit or one spell off before I can stealth. I wonder if I just had a spike in latency when that happened or if there is a un-noted aftercast delay. Can someone with Wukong test this out for me?

Comment: The reason why i can't test it again is because I dont own wukong and I played in during free week some time ago.

Comment: Are you using smart cast?

Comment: @Toast, yes I am. But i dont think it matters since decoy isn't a targeted spell.

Comment: There have been some previously reported bugs with smart cast and spell delays.  I can't find any official sources, just mentions within the forums.

Comment: Quick note - if Wukong is coming towards you and you right-click him for auto attack before he casts Nimbus Strike, when he gets in range you're going to hit him - there's nothing Wukong can do to prevent that damage. It's the same as Alistar trying to Headbutt Singed, if Singed casts his throw on Alistar before Alistar Headbutts, when Alistar gets in range Singed will throw him despite the Headbutt landing. Could that have been what happened?

Comment: Nonetheless, you could be genuinely experiencing lag, what computer are you using? I've found playing on my laptop reduces my ability to skill quickly, even with a strong internet connection. I usually play on a desktop with a direct connection to my router (none of this unreliable Wi-Fi silliness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for Wukong specifically, but there are cases of "after cast delay". Or, if you're familiar with fighting game mechanics, it's essentially "recovery" time from executing the attack. Once the recovery period is up, then you're able to resume your assault - otherwise, you must wait.

There's two different forms of skill "recovery" that are implemented in League of Legends for some skills.

The one you're probably experiencing is simply that there is a short recovery period after the resolution of the skill where you cannot act. For example (and this may just be what you're experiencing), Nimbus Strike has a tiny delay between when you make contact with your staff and when you can start acting again. There's a short delay after Blitzcrank purges his Static Field before he can start moving, and Ezreal's Arcane Shift has a tiny delay after you arrive before you can use another skill or attack. The logic behind this is essentially an extension of the reason you can't use skills or attack in the middle of the action to begin with - you're still in the middle of using the other skill. It rate limits your ability to chain skills instantly together. Contrast something like Tristana's Rocket Jump, where you *can* use skills even in mid-air.

The other form is that some champions, namely Sona and Udyr, *do* have a forced cooldown on all of their skills after using any single one. In their case, this is to simply rate-limit their ability to cast their spells sequentially - no song spamming, and no ridiculous stance chains.

Comment: Make sense! Thanks! And another champion with force cooldown is Udyr and his stances.

Comment: @Jay Udyr was free, like, twice in two months when I first started League of Legends, which I decided not to try him at the time. I have not seen him since, argh. But for the same reason as on Sona, it makes sense for him to have that cooldown system.

Comment: Any chance of providing a source to this?  I attribute the "recovery" to the animation of the skill, which can normally be negated by immediately moving, using a different skill, etc.

Comment: @Toast Not all things can be negated by moving - you can cancel some animations but not all. For example, you can't just move in the middle of Nimbus Strike - the "recovery" is merely the followthrough of the animation after what one might *perceive* to have been the end. But in reality, the motion is still happening. Compare flashing while still moving with a champion to Ezreal using Arcane Shift and then moving - there's a distinct pause.

Comment: Skarner's Crystal Slash, for example, has recovery with respect to using basic attacks, but you're still free to move and use other skills while the animation persists. Caitlyn, on the other hand, just about the moment her Piltover Peacemaker finishes firing you can start moving - its recover is slim to nonexistent.

Comment: Here's a video of Ez using his skill and then immediately auto attacking.  I'm really interested in reading up on this if you can find a source.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji5MmpM63Y4

Comment: @Toast I think we're differing on where we define the end of Arcane Shift with respect to when "immediately" begins. I see a distinct delay between when the teleport completes and when he gets to start making an action - the part where he generates the bullet from the spell itself. In fact, he actually uses Mystic Shot before making a normal attack, but that's also waiting until after the full effect of Arcane Shift completes. That's the kind of recovery I'm referring to. I'll be happy to talk with you on chat if you want a more comfortable exchange than comments.

Comment: I mostly just want a source. =D  The video is a little misleading but watch bottom lane EZs health.  He starts to mystic shot, instead Shifts, immediately auto attacks, completes the mystic shot and auto attacks again.

Comment: @Toast My source is personal experience with Ezreal, haha. I'm not seeing an auto-attack before the mystic shot. I see three changes to enemy Ezreal's health - from the Arcane Shift, from the Mystic Shot, and then the auto-attack. In that order. I'm not seeing a hit between the Arcane Shift and the Mystic Shot.

Comment: @Toast I just played a Custom game with [Rapida](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3015/rapida) to test this - there's no autoattack between Arcane Shift and the Mystic Shot. It would've been visible as day to see the extra shot if that were the case. Again, it's still honestly part of the actual animation for Arcane Shift, so one might not really call it distinct enough to be considered some kind of "recovery" mechanic, but it's essentially the same effect that would cause a delay after Nimbus Strike if you misperceive when it ends.

Comment: My bad.  I forgot Arcane Shift does damage.  Thanks for the great answers!

Answer (score 1):

(Was to long to add as a comment on the answer above so added as an answer)

The delay on ability's is technically called a Global Cool-down the time it takes for the spell to fully go off before your next ability is available you can auto attack during this time but not use another ability for .25 to .5 of a second depending on the ability used its why when you cast one you get a slight delay before the next ability goes off (The Term Global Cool-down originated from WoW and in that case is defined as the cool-down which starts every time you start to cast a spell, and it affects all of your spells. There are exceptions to this, however, as noted below. The basic rule of thumb is that if the spell affects the casting of the next spell, it will not activate the global cool-down.) But is the reason why you see a .5 second delay on the next ability you use as for example Wukong but i reiterate THIS DOES NOT AFFECT AUTO ATTACKS ON COOL-DOWNS

Answer (score -1):

Nothing in [Wukong's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wukong_the_Monkey_King) abilities mention an additional cool-down after using an ability (unlike Udyr).  Remember that you're target-able while dashing forward, so an enemy with good reactions could target you then.

It could also be a latency issue, or some other hardware related delay.